# How to do a double bucle to complete missing information using different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to complete missing information in some rows from a column in a dataframe, using another dataframe. I have in the first `df(dfPivote)`, two columns of interest  `'Entrega'` and `'Transportador'` which is the one with missing information. I have a second df (`dfTransportadoEntregadoFaltante`) with two columns of interest `'EntregaBusqueda'` which is the key to my other df, and `'Transportador'` with the information missing from the other df. I have the following code, and it is not working. How could I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example of what you have done? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using dataframe operations to fill in missing values. If I've followed your example code correctly, I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create fake data
# "dfPivote" dataframe with an empty string in the "Transportador" column:  
dfPivote = pd.DataFrame({'Entrega':[1,2,3],'Transportador':['a','','c']})

# "dfTransportadoEntregadoFaltante" lookup dataframe
dfTransportadoEntregadoFaltante = pd.DataFrame({'EntregaBusqueda':[1,2,3], 'Transportador':['a','b','c']})


# 1. Replace empty strings in dfPivote['Transportador'] with np.nan values:

dfPivote['Transportador'] = dfPivote['Transportador'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x)==0 else x)


# 2. Merge the two dataframes together on the "Entrega" and "EntregaBusqueda" columns respectively:

df = dfPivote.merge(dfTransportadoEntregadoFaltante, left_on='Entrega', right_on='EntregaBusqueda', how='left')

#   Entrega Transportador_x EntregaBusqueda Transportador_y
#       1       a       1       a
#       2       NaN     2       b
#       3       c       3       c


# 3. Fill NaNs in "Transportador_x" column with corresponding values in "Transportador_y" column:

df['Transportador_x'] = df['Transportador_x'].fillna(df['Transportador_y'])

#   Entrega Transportador_x EntregaBusqueda Transportador_y
#      1    a   1   a
#      2    b   2   b
#      3    c   3   c
```